# Django: views and assert like returns

Tags: python, django, assert

I wonder if there is a python hackish way to achieve the following:

I found myself using an assert like structure in my views a lot:

```
def view(request):
    if not condition:
        return HttpResponseServerError("error")

    if not condition2:
        return HttpResponseServerError("error2")

    [...]

    return HttpResponse("OK!")
```

So I thought about using an assert like function:

```
def view(request):
    def err(msg=None):
        msg = msg if msg else "Illegal Parameters"
        resp = {"msg": msg}
        resp = json.dumps(resp)
        return HttpResponseServerError(resp)

    def verify(exp, msg=None):
        if not exp:
            err(msg)

    verify(condition, "error")

    verify(condition2, "error2")

    return HttpResponse("OK")
```

Obviously, this does not work, as the result of the error function is never returned. Furthermore, I would also need to return the Response all the way to the view function and run `return verify()`, which will make my code prevent from execution of course.

One possible solution would be a decorator that either returns an error or the view function after all asserts went through. However, I would like to prevent that, as I also need some of the values I am establishing (imagine parsing one number after another and then having to pass a list of numbers).

Another solution I could think of is to actually do use a decorator and make my function a generator, yielding the result of verify. The decorator is a loop over that generator and keeps going until a response is yielded.

But in this post I am really looking for a more hackish way, to let the nested function return a reponse instead of the parent function and therefore prevent execution.

I will post my yield "solution" in a separate answer so you can get the picture :)

Comment: Why not exceptions? I think that's how `get_object_or_404()` is implemented, for example.

Comment: I feel like hitting myself with a stick now...

Comment: @rodrigo However, if you do throw an exception, it limits your possibilities unless you catch it (in a decorator maybe xP). If I want to return a proper JSON response that just contains an `error: True` for example.

Comment: Yes, if there is more than one view you want to do this, a decorator is the way to go. If it is only one view, it is not worth it.

Comment: Here, I've added an answer with all put together. I didn't test it, so take it as a sketch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about an exception, and a nice decorator to catch it:

```
class AssertError(Exception):
    pass

def assertLike(view):
    def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return view(request, *args, **kwargs):
        except AssertError as e:
            return HttpResponseServerError(...)
    return wrap

@assertLike
def createTask(request):
    import json
    ....
    if not exp:
        raise AssertError()
    ....
    return HttpResponse("Ok")
```

Comment: I really like the idea. Better than mine, as it clears up the syntax from using yield a lot. I consider implementing it in a module with a proper exception that allows to pass around responses!

Answer (score 0):

Here I present the generator based solution:

```
def assertLike(view):
    def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
        for response in view(request, *args, **kwargs):
            if response:
                return response
    return wrap


@other_django_views
@another_django_view
@assertLike
def createTask(request):
    import json

    def err(msg=None):
        msg = msg if msg else "Illegal Parameters"
        resp = {"msg": msg}
        resp = json.dumps(resp)
        return HttpResponseServerError(resp)

    def verify(exp, msg=None):
        if not exp:
            return err(msg)

    # only react to ajax requests
    yield verify(True, "This is not an error")
    yield verify(False, "Here it should stop!")

    yield HttpResponse("This is the final response!")
```